Horror movie with teenagers tormented by a summoned demon
The film starts off with 4 or 5 students that try communicating with the dead. One of them uses a hand held camera and this "demon" comes through and picks up one girl and pulls her into the darkness.   
The movie then follows this guy who is her ex-boyfriend and was also there that night with his new girlfriend. They are house sitting her parents home when they are tormented from this same demon.   
Seemed very similar to paranormal activity in a sense. Anyone know the name of this movie?

Any other details that may help identification? When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? Any other plot details or descriptions you remember?

This sounds like The Apparition.  That movie opens on Tom Felton at college doing a recreation of The Philip Experiment, though in the movie they call it the Charles Experiment.  The idea, both in movie and not, is that you can "create" a ghost if you get enough people to believe in it.  In the movie they use some sort of mental amplifiers to "multiply their belief".
The rest of the movie is about vague hauntings following the guy (Sebastian Stan) who was there in the beginning, but ran off to do A/V installation work in Vegas.  I don't know if they're house sitting or if his new girlfriend's (Ashley Greene) parents bought them the house, but it's in a newly developed community in the middle of the desert.  There was a minor subplot involving the neighbors and the small dog they owned.
The haunting stuff tends to take the form of gross rot-looking black stuff growing on the house...
Any of that sound right?

ah you are a life saver, that is 100 % correct the movie i been looking for!

@ShaneCampbell Feel free to accept the answer if it is the correct solution to your problem.
